# How to pass the selected ListTile to another screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

The page displays the US states as a list. And when you click on the ListTile, a checkmark appears next to the state. The user can only select one state. How to track the state on which the click was made and transfer it to another screen? Send on button click "Save".

```js
List < UsaStatesModel > _statesList = [];
late final _checkedValue =
  List < bool > .generate(_statesList.length, (index) => false);

@override
Widget bodyWidget(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: 'States'
      actions: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Icon(
          Icons.save,
          size: 26.0,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    body: BlocConsumer < BlocA, BlocAState > (
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is StatesLoadedState) {
          _statesList = state.states;
        }
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is StatesLoadedState) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 142),
              child: ListView.separated(
                itemCount: _statesList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    trailing: !_checkedValue[index] ?
                    const SizedBox.shrink(): Image.asset(
                        Assets.assetsCheckmark,
                        width: 13,
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      title: Text(
                        _statesList[index].name,
                      ),
                      onTap: () => _checkState(index),
                  );
                },
                separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return const Divider();
                },
              ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
)
}

void _checkState(int index) {
  setState(
    () {
      for (var i = 0; i < _checkedValue.length; i++) {
        _checkedValue[i] = false;
      }
      _checkedValue[index] = true;
    },
  );
}
}
```

Comment: Now when user click on the ListTile, a checkbox appears (the user selects one state). And I need to transfer the name of the state to the previous screen when I click on the "Save" button. My problem is that I don't know how to keep track of the selected state and pass it by name.

Comment: I have a list with false values and using the _checkState function I change one value to true and here I need to pass it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable like this on top

```
int currentIndex = 0;
```

Whenever a list is selected update this index

```dart
void _checkState(int index) {
  setState(
    () {
      for (var i = 0; i < _checkedValue.length; i++) {
        _checkedValue[i] = false;
      }
      _checkedValue[index] = true;
     currentIndex = index; //update here
    },
  );
}
```

Now

```
_stateList[currentIndex]
```

Will give you the currently selected state

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass Listtile and it will occupied memory so i think you have to pass only data from one to another screen using parameter to another screen like this.

````
import 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
body: Container(
  child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {  

    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
      return secondscreen(data:"hello");
    }));
  },
  child: Text("hwllo"),),
),
    );
  }
}

class secondscreen extends StatefulWidget {

  String data;
   secondscreen({Key? key,required this.data}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<secondscreen> createState() => _secondscreenState();
}

class _secondscreenState extends State<secondscreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('${widget.data}');
  }
}```
````

Comment: You can try by passing ListTile object to another screen like this i think it will be worked best becuase if we can  pass String data then we must be pass ListTile Data also

Answer (score 0):

We can have selectedIndex property in this screen on top and assign value to it inside _checkState method. And in our second screen (Screen to which we have to pass the selected state), we need to create a UsaStatesModel variable and assign value to it on navigation.

```
 int? selectedIndex;


void _checkState(int index) {
  selectedIndex = index; // Assigning selected index value
  setState(
    () {
      for (var i = 0; i < _checkedValue.length; i++) {
        _checkedValue[i] = false;
      }
      _checkedValue[index] = true;
    },
  );
}

// Call this method on save to pass selected state to another screen
    goToAnotherScreen(BuildContext context) {
      if (selectedIndex != null) {
        final selectedState = _statesList[selectedIndex!];
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => SecondScreen(selectedState: selectedState),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Second screen

```
class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      const SecondScreen({
        Key? key,
        required this.selectedState,
      }) : super(key: key);
    
      UsaStatesModel selectedState;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container();
      }
    }
```